# Editor Templates rendering multiple times (using Jquery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, editortemplates

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
 Public string PersonName{get; set;}
 Public string NumberOfCars{get;set;} // DropDown
}
Public Class CarViewModel
{
 Public string CareMake{get; set;}
Public string  Year{get; set;}
}
```

On a Page I have to display PersonViewModel  related controls.
Based on Number Of Cars selected( 2 or 3) I should be showing  Input fields for CarViewModel (Which is an Editor Template)

Problem: I  have written  Editor Template for CarViewModel. Not sure how to call it dynamically based on drop down selected (i.e., NumberOfCars selected by person).

**PS**

- I can Create Partial views and render multiple times dynamically based on dropdown selection.  But not sure How to model bind child(CarViewModel) to
  Parent ViewModel which is PersonViewModel in case.
- I haven't written all code for easy understanding of problem.

Comment: Is the idea that if you select 3 then 3 sets or controls will be created to add 3 new cars? And what do you mean bind to the parent PersonViewModel? `PersonViewModel` does not contain a property `IEnumerable<CarViewModel>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes. When I select 3 then 3 sets or controls will be created to add 3 new cars. While doing post back How can I do model binding. The only way I see to to post  data is through Jquery.

Comment: If `PersonViewModel` contained property `List<CarViewModel> Cars` then you would call a server method that initializes a new `PersonViewModel` with 3 default `Car` objects in the list and return a partial view containing the controls for the 3 cars. But a more typical approach is just to have an 'Add car` button and dynamically add new cars. A pure client side approach is [shown in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689)